# Determine if a range of cell values contain 5 or more consecutive negative values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to figure out a way to determine if a dataset of 'X' values in a column contains 5 or more consecutive negative numbers. If so, how many times does that happen (5 negatives in consecutive cells).

Example data:
-110
-164
-101
-144
-117
0
0
10
15
22
-56
-60
-54
2
10
0

In this example I would expect the result to be "1" since 5 consecutive negative integers occurs only once in the dataset.
I built a nasty nested IF statement run to figure this out but I know there's an easier way.
I cannot seem to get a shorter formula to work.

Appreciate anyone's input

Answer (score 1):

You can try `FREQUENCY` function:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A:A<0,ROW(A:A)),IF(A:A>=0,ROW(A:A)))>=5))
```

for older excel versions it must be entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image]

Comment: Nice. That is working exactly as expected. Thanks very much for this